# Best way to initialize an array through inheritance

Tags: php, arrays, inheritance, initialization

I would like to initialize an array through inheritance definition with the following constraints :

1. no constructor
2. simple usage for developer using BaseClass as defined below

**Edit** : String arrays are given as examples for better lisibility, arrays will be loaded with objects in the "real" world

One way can be merging parent array in each subclass initArray function , so for each sub Class:

```
public function initArray() {
    return array_merge (
        parent::initArray(),
        array ("C1")
    );
}
```

**but I would like to avoid it (constraint 2)**

Any ideas? Other possible implementations? Existing patterns?
Thank you

```
Class BaseClass {
    protected $myArray;
    public function initArray() {
        return array ();
    }
    public function init(){
        $this->myArray=$this->initArray();
    }
    public function getMyArray() {
        return $this->myArray;
    }
}
Class B extends BaseClass {
    public function initArray() {
        return array ("B1", "B2", "B3");
    }
}

Class C extends B {
    public function initArray() {
        return array ("C1");
    }
}
$c=new C();
$c->init();
print_r($c->getMyArray()); // return C1 and I would like C1, B1, B2, B3
```

Answer (score 0):

[Push](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php) inside your array, don't return:

```
Class BaseClass {
    protected $myArray;
    public function init(){
        $this->myArray=[];
    }
    public function getMyArray() {
        return $this->myArray;
    }
}
Class B extends BaseClass {
    public function initArray() {
        array_push($this->myArray, "B1", "B2", "B3");
    }
}

Class C extends B {
    public function initArray() {
        $this->init();
        parent::initArray();
        array_push($this->myArray, "C1");
    }
}
$c=new C();
$c->initArray();
print_r($c->getMyArray()); // return C1 and I would like C1, B1, B2, B3
```

PS: This question lacks good old polymorphism, but it's just a quick resolution, you should improve this algorithm.

Hey, try that!

```
    <?php
Class BaseClass {
    protected $myArray = array();
    public function __construct($content = false) {
        if ($content){
            array_push($this->myArray, explode(',', $content));
        }
    }
    public function getMyArray() {
        return $this->myArray[0];
    }
}
Class B extends BaseClass {
    public function __construct($content) {
        parent::__construct("$content,B1,B2,B3");
    }
}

Class C extends B {
    public function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct('C1');
    }
}
$c=new C();
print_r($c->getMyArray()); // return C1 and I would like C1, B1, B2, B3
```

Example improved to accept objects:

```
<?php
Class BaseClass {
    protected $myArray = array();
    public function __construct($content = false, $content2 = false) {
        if ($content){
            if (is_array($content)){
                array_push($this->myArray, $content);
            } else if (is_object($content)) {
                if ($content2) {
                    $convContent = array_merge((array) $content2, (array) $content);
                } else {
                    $convContent = get_object_vars($content);
                }
                array_push($this->myArray, $convContent);
            } else {
                array_push($this->myArray, explode(',', $content));
            }
        }
    }
    public function getMyArray() {
        return $this->myArray[0];
    }
}
Class B extends BaseClass {
    private $cont1 = 'B1';
    private $cont2 = 'B2';
    private $cont3 = 'B3';
    public function __construct($content = false) {
        parent::__construct($this, $content);
    }
}

Class C extends B {
    private $cont1 = 'C1';
    public function  __construct($content = false) {
        parent::__construct($this, $content);
    }
}
$c=new C();
print_r($c->getMyArray()); // return C1 and I would like C1, B1, B2, B3
```

Comment: your code will not work, because `$this->myArray` is not initialized when you use the `array_push`

Comment: Correct (the modified version following Edwin comment), However it is not simple for usage (constraint 2) but a bit less complex than the array_merge method I proposed. Note : it is really a question of design for developer usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the array, you can do like this [eval.in code](https://eval.in/801192)

```
<?php
Class BaseClass {
    protected $myArray;
    public function initArray() {
        return array ();
    }
    public function init(){
        $this->myArray=$this->initArray();
    }
    public function getMyArray() {
        return $this->myArray;
    }
}
Class B extends BaseClass {
    public function initArray() {
        $parentArray = parent::initArray();
        $parentArray[]="B1";
        $parentArray[]="B2";
        $parentArray[]="B3";
        return $parentArray;
    }
}

Class C extends B {
    public function initArray() {
        $parentArray = parent::initArray();
        $parentArray[]="C1";
        return $parentArray;
    }
}
$c=new C();
$c->init();
print_r($c->getMyArray()); // return C1 and I would like C1, B1, B2, B3
```

Comment: Correct, However it is not simple for usage (constraint 2) and also I would prefer the array_merge method I proposed.

Comment: oh, I didn't see your first snippet. But the `array_merge` should be better

Answer (score 0):

This code is working (supposing that BaseClass has no constructor).
It answers the question, however I feel it heavy!!

```
Class BaseClass {
    protected $myArray;
    public function initArray() {
        return array ();
    }
    public function getMyArray() {
        if ($this->myArray===null) $this->_initArray();
        return $this->myArray;
    }
    private function _initArray() {
        $ancestors=$this->_getAncestors(static::Class);
        $this->myArray=array();
        foreach ($ancestors as $ancestor) {
            /** @var BaseClass $ancestorInstance */
            $ancestorInstance = new $ancestor();
            $this->myArray=array_merge($this->myArray, $ancestorInstance->initArray());
        }
    }
    private function _getAncestors ($class) {
        for ($classes[] = $class; $class = get_parent_class ($class); $classes[] = $class);
        return $classes;
    }
}
Class B extends BaseClass {
    public function initArray() {
        return array ("B1", "B2", "B3");
    }
}
Class C extends B {
    public function initArray() {
        return array ("C1");
    }
}
$c=new C();
$myArray=$c->getMyArray();
print_r($myArray); // returns now C1, B1, B2, B3
```

Comment: Note : it supposes that all BaseClass children have a initArray method... What a nightmare

Comment: why would you do this?

Comment: I am building a framework and I would like that the developers write less code as possible so enjoy using it. I have proposed a solution but seems heavy, will have to look at performance vs usage. Thank you for sharing thoughts.

Comment: I feel that you make this more complicated that it needs to be

Comment: true lol. Perhaps the requirements are wrong but that was the requirements.

Comment: @thipages Review my edit, I improved that.

Your solution is heavy and is not scalable. When the product grows, that iteration will result into serious performance issues.

Comment: Hi, nice trick. However, I want no constructor and more than that :  String array were given as example, in real world this is not string arrays but object arrays that are used (I should have say that). Thank you

Comment: Man, I avoided your constraint, you don't mentioned about no constructors and arrays/objects can be used improving the conditions of main constructor. Stack won't solve all your problems, but giving directions. 

Btw, using no constructors when the language lacks strong polymorphism doesn't have sense, but ok. You're welcome.

Comment: Yes sorry about string vs object, I did not metion it (I added it to the question). However no constructor requirement was in the initial post. For ploymorphism and object construction, I dont know ... object construction ensures that the instance property state is well formed and true is a part of polymorphism. Nevertheless, that was probably a weird question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

One answer can be the following (including inheritance method holes). My god! If someone has a better solution ....

```
Class BaseClass {
    protected $myArray;
    public function initArray() {
        return array ();
    }
    public function getMyArray() {
        if ($this->myArray===null) $this->_initArray();
        return $this->myArray;
    }
    private function _initArray() {
        $ancestors=$this->_getAncestors(static::Class);
        $this->myArray=array();
        foreach ($ancestors as $ancestor) {
            /** @var BaseClass $ancestorInstance */
            $ancestorInstance = new $ancestor();
            if ($this->_checkIfMethodIsPresent($ancestor, 'initArray')) {
                $this->myArray = array_merge($this->myArray, $ancestorInstance->initArray());
            }
        }
    }
    private function _getAncestors ($class) {
        for ($classes[] = $class; $class = get_parent_class ($class); $classes[] = $class);
        return $classes;
    }
    private function _checkIfMethodIsPresent($className, $methodName) {
        $reflector = new ReflectionClass($className);
        $found=false;
        foreach ($reflector->getMethods() as $method) {
            if ($method->class == $className && $methodName==$method->name) {
                $found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $found;
    }
}
Class B extends BaseClass {
    public function initArray() {
        return array ("B1", "B2", "B3");
    }
}
Class C extends B {
    // No initArray method
}
Class D extends C {
    public function initArray() {
        return array ("D1");
    }
}
$d=new D();
$myArray=$d->getMyArray();
print_r($myArray); // returns now D1, B1, B2, B3
```